# How to remove matched words from end of String

Tags: java

I want to remove the following words from end of String `‘PTE’, ‘LTD’, ‘PRIVATE’ and ‘LIMITED’`

i tried the code but then i stuck. i tried this

```
String[] str = {"PTE", "LTD", "PRIVATE", "LIMITED"};

String company = "Basit LTD";
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {

    if (company.endsWith(str[i])) {

        int position = company.lastIndexOf(str[i]);
        company = company.substring(0, position);        
    }
}

System.out.println(company.replaceAll("\\s",""));
```

It worked. But suppose the company is `Basit LIMITED PRIVATE LTD PTE` or `Basit LIMITED PRIVATE PTE LTD` or any combination of four words in the end. Then the above code just remove the last name i.e., `PTE` or `PRIVATE` and so on, and the output is `BasitLIMITEDPRIVATELTD`.

I want output to be just `Basit`

How can i do it?

Thanks

**---------------Edit---**

Please note here the company name is just an example, it is not necessary that it is always the same. may be i have name like

```
String company = "Masood LIMITED LTD PTE PRIVATE"
```

or any name that can have the above mentioned words at the end.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the space char before each word you remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the unwanted words in the map it will be ommitted in the resultant string

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("PTE", "");
    map.put("LTD", "");
    map.put("PRIVATE", "");
    map.put("LIMITED", "");



    String company = "Basit LTD PRIVATE PTE";


    String words[] = company.split(" ");

    String resultantStr = "";

    for(int k = 0; k < words.length; k++){
        if(map.get(words[k]) == null) {
            resultantStr += words[k] + " ";

        }
    }


    resultantStr = resultantStr.trim();
    System.out.println(" Trimmed String: "+  resultantStr);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in single line. no need to loop through. just use [**String#replaceAll(regex, str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
company = company.replaceAll("PTE$*?|LTD$*?|PRIVATE$*?|LIMITED$*?","");
```

Comment: This will also remove the string inside another word.

Comment: @baraky din't get what you mean.

Comment: If the line was: "COMPTETITION LIMITED..." it will change first word to COMTITION

Comment: You should add $ at the end of every string. This sign specifies end of string.

Comment: @PremGenError i tried this `String company = "Basit LIMITED PRIVATE PTE LTD";` --> `company = company.replaceAll("PTE$|LTD$|PRIVATE$|LIMITED$","");` --> `System.out.println(company);`  but it is printing `Basit LIMITED PRIVATE PTE ` not just `Basit`... ?

Comment: I have just tested this doesn't work. Also I have placed my answer which i have tested as well

Comment: @baraky now its recursive. :)

Comment: this method will remove the words PTE or Private found within the strings as well for example "BasitPTE LIMITED PRIVATE LTD PTE" will result in Basit.

Comment: BasitLTDemar LIMITED PRIVATE LTD PTE" This will result in Basitemar hence removing LTD from the first word itself.

Comment: Thanks. Now that is really cool:). Can you please explain it to me how this rejex is working in this case ?

Comment: @Basit am glad it worked, look here for regex tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html also as noted by User_CC look this doesn't work if you have your regex string embebed inside another string. keep that in mind too.. :)

Comment: @PremGenError Wait .... Yes User_CC is right if i have name like `"BasitLTDMasood  LIMITED";` then i am ending up with `BasitMasood`. It shouldn't be happen ... :( In this case the output should be `BasitLTDMasood` ....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove these suffixes only at the end of the string, then you could introduce a `while` loop:

```
String[] str = {"PTE", "LTD", "PRIVATE", "LIMITED"};
boolean foundSuffix = true;

String company = "Basit LTD";

while (foundSuffix) {
    foundSuffix = false;

    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {

        if (company.endsWith(str[i])) {
            foundSuffix = true;
            int position = company.lastIndexOf(str[i]);
            company = company.substring(0, position);        
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(company.replaceAll("\\s",""));
```

If you don't mind transforming `PTE Basit LIMITED INC` to `Basit` (and also remove the first PTE), then `replaceAll` should work, as explained by others.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do exactly same thing for one of my projects. I wrote this code few days earlier. Now I was exactly trying to find a much better way to do it, that's how I found this Question. But after seeing other answers I decided to share my version of the code.

```
Collection<String> stopWordSet = Arrays.asList("PTE", "LTD", "PRIVATE", "LIMITED");    

String company = "Basit LTD"; //Or Anything
String[] tokens = company.split("[\@\]\\\_\^\[\"\#\ \!\&\'\`\$\%\*\+\(\)\.\/\,\-\;\~\:\}\|\{\?\>\=\<]+");

Stack<String> tokenStack = new Stack<>();
tokenStack.addAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
while (!tokenStack.isEmpty()) {
     String token = tokenStack.peek();
     if (stopWordSet.contains(token))
         tokenStack.pop();
     else
         break;
}

String formattedCompanyName = StringUtils.join(tokenStack.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String a[]) {   
    String[] str = {"PTE", "LTD", "PRIVATE", "LIMITED"};
    String company = "Basit LIMITED PRIVATE LTD PTE";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        company = company.replaceAll(str[i], "");
    }

    System.out.println(company.replaceAll("\\s",""));
}
```

Comment: No the name is just an example, it can be any combination, here i hardcoded string just for example like may be i have company name `Masood PRIVATE PTE LTD LIMITED`...

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use `trim()` and call your function recursively, Or each time you remove a sub string from the end, reset your `i` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringMatchRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str="my name is noorus khan";
        String search="noorus";
        String newString="";
        String word=str.replace(search," ");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(word," ");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
          newString = newString + st.nextToken() + " "; 
        }
        System.out.println(newString);

    }
```

first using the replace method we get `word=my name is ..... khan` (Note: here(`.`) represents the space). Now we should have to remove these spaces for that we are creating a new string adding all the token simply.

Output: `my name is khan`